# Take a ScreenShot on test failure via TestNG before @AfterMethod (Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, testng, screenshot

I have ApplicationTest class with tests methods where I have tests and `@BeforeMethod` and `@AfterMethod`, that contains initialization and cleanup respectively.

```
public class ApplicationTest extends BaseTest {

....

@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void openHomePage() {

    ......

    headerPage.openMyApplicationsPage();
    myAppPage.openAddNewAppPage();
    newAppPage.createApp(appWithoutImages);

    headerPage.openMyApplicationsPage();
    myAppPage.openAddNewAppPage();
    newAppPage.createApp(appWithImages);


}

@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void cleanUp() {
    headerPage.openMyApplicationsPage();
    if (myAppPage.isApplicationPresent(appWithoutImages.getTitle())){
        myAppPage.openApp(appWithoutImages.getTitle());
        appPage.deleteApp();
    }
    headerPage.openMyApplicationsPage();
    if (myAppPage.isApplicationPresent(appWithImages.getTitle())){
        myAppPage.openApp(appWithImages.getTitle());
        appPage.deleteApp();
    }
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
}

@Test
public void correctInformationAboutApplicationTest() {
.....
}

@Test
public void testAppCreationWithoutImages() {
....
}

@Test
public void testAppEditing() {

}

}
```

It exstends of BaseTest class where I wrote logic of taking screenshot of failed tests:

```
    public class BaseTest {
    private static Settings settings = new Settings();

    @BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    public static void beforeSuite() {
        driver = settings.getDriver();

        BasePage.settings = settings;

        driver.get(settings.getBaseUrl());

        if (!settings.getBrowser().equals(BrowserType.HTMLUNIT))
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @AfterSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    public static void afterClass() {
        driver.close();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void takeScreenshotWhenFailure(ITestResult result) {
        String testDate = getCurrentDateAndTimeInSting();
        if (ITestResult.FAILURE == result.getStatus()) {
            captureScreenshot(result.getName() + " - " + testDate);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is implementation of this method:

```
public static void captureScreenshot(String screenshotName) {

    String pathToScreenshotDirectory = PATH_TO_SCREENSHOTS + " - " + TEST_DATE_FOR_PACKAGE;

    try {
        createDirectory(pathToScreenshotDirectory);
        TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
        File screenshot = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File(pathToScreenshotDirectory + "\\" + screenshotName + ".png"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    log.info("Screenshot taken: [ " + screenshotName + " ]");
}
```

It works ok in other test classes where there is no `@AfterMethod`, but in ApplicationTest class it takes screenshot after `@AfterMethod` of ApplicationTest class and it is wrong screenshot, because it is not a screenshot  after `@Test` method.

How can I take a correct screenshot for failed test after `@Test` method in ApplicationTest class, but not after `@AfterMethod` of `ApplicationTest` class.

> So it have to be in next order (if we start count with @Test):
>
> 1. **@Test**
> 2. **@AfterMethod** of `BaseTest` class
> 3. **@AfterMethod** of `ApplicationTest` class

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try

```
 @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println("***** Error "+result.getName()+" test has failed *****");
        String methodName=result.getName().toString().trim();
        takeScreenShot(methodName);
```

in your application class itself.